# How do I distinguish between an EOF character, and the actual end of file?

Tags: eof

When reading a file, I understand the last character provided is an <kbd>EOF</kbd>. Now, what happens, when I have an `EOF` character in that file?

How do I distinguish between the "real" end of a file, and the `EOF` character?

Comment: You *can't* have an "EOF character" in the file. There's no such thing

Comment: In DOS there was, and there still can be in Windows. Ctrl-Z, or ASCII value 26.  One such application that still produces files with `EOF` characters is a product named WinQuery from The Analytical Group.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I decided to move my comments to an answer.

You *can't* have an "EOF character" in your file because there is no such thing. The underlying filesystem knows how many bytes are in a file; it doesn't rely on the contents of the file to know where the end is.

The C functions you're using return `EOF` (-1) *but that wasn't read from the file*. It's just the way the function tells you that you're reached the end. And because -1 isn't a valid character in any character set, there's no confusion.

Answer (score 4):

You need some context for this question. On Windows, there's the outdated DOS concept of a real "EOF character" -- Ctrl-Z. It is actually not possible to tell a "real" one from a "fake" one; a file with an embedded Ctrl-Z will contain some trailing hidden data from the perspective of a program which is actually looking for Ctrl-Z as an end of file character. Don't try to write this kind of code anymore -- it's not necessary.

In the portable C API and on UNIX, a 32-bit `-1` is used to indicate end of file, which can't be a valid 8 or 16-bit character, so it's easy to tell the difference.

Comment: Erm, ok, it seems I have confused `EOF` and `EOT`, which I thought was basically the same thing. Ctrl + D is often called "end of file".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about C, `EOF` is -1, which is not a character (hence there is no confusion).

Comment: So, when I put an `EOF` character in a file, it won't register as end of file?

Comment: A `char` is a byte (8 bit value), whereas EOF is an integer.  There is no such thing as an EOF character and thus you can't put one in a file.