# EOF file character in a string/buffer

Tags: node.js, linux, operating-system

I was reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9091262/4260745) that we can't have `EOF` character in the file but I saw in one of the open source libraries [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/strip-eof) that it treats `\n` as the `EOF` which seems completely wrong to me.

Which the correct approach?

Comment: That node module just has an unfortunate name. As you read, there is no EOF character.

Comment: @mscdex yes that got me rally confused and the others are using in the same context, I think I should raise an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link is talking about the EOF character code which was used in DOS files to signify the end of an entire file.

The second link unfortunately is probably a misnomer as eof is used in what should be eol - end of line - or in other words newline.  That's exactly what the /n char represents.

So you are right - eof is not consistent.