# Terminating [user]. with a EOT character in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am writing a wrapper for a Prolog interpreter used from a different programming language. I don't go into detail, but it basically generates a conforming Prolog program and feeds the program to an interpreter from the standard input. I am relatively new to Prolog.

The problem is, I could not find the specification for `[user].` term that reads the rules from the standard input. Specifically, how it detects the end of the input.

The most intuitive way to achieve this is to send an EOT character (Ctrl-D), but it does not seem to work. Below is an illustrative example, replace the ^D with an actual EOT character. Assume this file is saved in `input.pl`. I intend to generate such code programatically and feed it to the background prolog process through the standard input.

```
[user].
factorial(0,1).
factorial(N,F) :- (>(N,0),is(N1,-(N,1)),factorial(N1,F1),is(F,*(N,F1))).
^D
factorial(3,W).
```

When I run `cat input.pl | <prolog>` where `<prolog>` is whatever Prolog interpreter (swipl, yap, etc.), it does not seem to recognize ^D. Why is this and how do I solve this? On the terminal ^D works fine.

Above example is supposed to return "W=6". SWI complains `Syntax error: illegal_character`. Yap seems to ignore ^D, just parse everything and return `yes`.

Of course I can write the program onto a temporary file and tell the interpreter to consult the file, but it is slow.

Comment: EOF is not the same thing as a stream being at end-of-file or being closed. `[user].` tells Prolog to read from the user until the stream ends or an end-of-file is signaled. The terminal converts the user's Ctrl-D into that signal. It isn't a literal character that appears in the input stream. Otherwise, how would you be able to `cat` a file with EOF characters in it?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9091262/812818).

Comment: Not EOF, EOT. I don't expect `[user].` is detecting the EOF.

Comment: Say `end_of_file.` in place of ^D

Comment: @DanielLyons Literal EOF character does not exist but literal EOT character exists, which is a character code 0x04. Since `[user].` is a special alias it does not need to detect the end of file either. In fact, if you truely "ends the file" by e.g. closing the pipe then the process will be killed by SIGPIPE.
You didn't answer my real question, but your answer reminded me of launching the swipl subprocess in a tty. Then I can write 0x04=^D to the input of the tty from the host language.

Comment: @false thanks, this answers my real question. Will test soon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say `end_of_file.` in place of `^D`.  This works in many Prolog implementations because their actual reading is performed with `read/1`.  Historically, from DECsystem 10 Prolog on, systems only had `read/1` but did not have `at_end_of_stream/0` and related built-in predicates. In fact, some programmers used `end_of_file.` within a Prolog source file to permit appending arbitrary text to a Prolog source.